# Only my default Virtual Host will execute PHP scripts--500 error otherwise

Tags: apache-2.2, php, virtualhost, httpd, 500-error

This should be a simple thing to find, but I've spent over an hour on it--time to ask for some assistance.  I have a very basic CentOS 5.5 box running two virtual machines.  The first machine has been up for several weeks without any issues and accepts connections over 80 and 443 with a signed SSL cert.

Today I went in to add a second Virtual Host entry for a site that will only need to listen on 80.  I set up the VM as I normally do, created a SIMPLE index.php script that contains only the word 'test'.

If I mv that file to index.html the page loads just fine, but when it is index.php I get a 500 error:

> HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server
>   Error): An unexpected condition was
>   encountered while the server was
>   attempting to fulfill the request.

In my logs I get no errors but the access log shows:

> [11/May/2011:11:35:26 -0500] "GET /
>   HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0
>   (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7)
>   AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/11.0.696.65 Safari/534.24"

The original site is a PHP/MySQL site and is working just fine!  At this point I am just out of ideas for where to look so any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Shane

Answer (score 0):

Are any other PHP files loading correctly on the 2nd VM?

Create a simple php page to test

save as test.php under your 2nd VM web directory and browse to it.. This will give you an idea if its related to the PHP install, your apache, etc.

I would also check the errors.log if you haven't already.. Better yet, tail -f errors.log while you attempt to access a PHP page.